# Spring url-pattern and @RequestMapping for home page

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have the following config in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>orchard</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/orchard/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/orchard</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the following @RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value={"", "/","/home"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(Model model, Principal principal, HttpSession session)
```

But to access the home page i need to go to either:

```
http://host:8080/app/orchard/ or http://host:8080/app/orchard/home
```

if i omit the slash as in:

```
http://host:8080/app/orchard
```

I get a 404. Have i done something wrong in the config here?

Cheers,
NFV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this request mapping, I think this should work for you:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/*", "/home"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

This will be a catch-all though, if any other mapping is not found, it will default to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Create index.jsp page under webapps folder and from there you should forward to home.html,  using jsp:forward tag

Comment: The mapping is to a Spring controller, not a jsp.

Comment: Dude I am talking about a welcome page. You get to define a welcome page and from there you can forward to your home page. Use
    <jsp:forward page="/orchard/home.html"/>

Your controller mapping should work fine with this kind of welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the space in `@RequestMapping` do not work , try this

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>orchard</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

change the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/orchard","/orchard/home"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String homePage(Model model, Principal principal, HttpSession session)
```